# Should time.perf_counter() be consistent across processes in Python on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, time, multiprocessing

**UPDATE**: A fix for this bug has been committed and will debut in Python 3.10, expected to be released Oct 2021. See the [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue37205#msg381107) for details.

---

The documentation for [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) indicates that it is *system-wide*

> time.**perf_counter()** → float
>
> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a
> clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration.
> It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide. The
> reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the
> difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

Am I incorrect in interpreting *system-wide* to include consistency across processes?

As shown below, it appears to be consistent on Linux, but not on Windows. In addition, Windows behavior with Python 3.6 is significantly different to 3.7.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can point out documentation or bug reports covering this behavior.

### Test case

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def worker():
    return time.perf_counter()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
    futures = []
    for i in range(3):
        print('Submitting worker {:d} at time.perf_counter() == {:.3f}'.format(i, time.perf_counter()))
        futures.append(pool.submit(worker))
        time.sleep(1)

    for i, f in enumerate(futures):
        print('Worker {:d} started at time.perf_counter() == {:.3f}'.format(i, f.result()))
```

### Results on Windows 7

```
C:\...>Python36\python.exe -VV
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

C:\...>Python36\python.exe perf_counter_across_processes.py
Submitting worker 0 at time.perf_counter() == 0.000
Submitting worker 1 at time.perf_counter() == 1.169
Submitting worker 2 at time.perf_counter() == 2.170
Worker 0 started at time.perf_counter() == 0.000
Worker 1 started at time.perf_counter() == 0.533
Worker 2 started at time.perf_counter() == 0.000

C:\...>Python37\python.exe -VV
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

C:\...>Python37\python.exe perf_counter_across_processes.py
Submitting worker 0 at time.perf_counter() == 0.376
Submitting worker 1 at time.perf_counter() == 1.527
Submitting worker 2 at time.perf_counter() == 2.529
Worker 0 started at time.perf_counter() == 0.380
Worker 1 started at time.perf_counter() == 0.956
Worker 2 started at time.perf_counter() == 1.963
```

I've omitted further results on Windows for brevity, but the same behavior was observed on Windows 8.1. In addition, Python 3.6.7 behaved the same as 3.6.8, while Python 3.7.1 behaved the same as 3.7.3.

### Results on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

```
$ python3 -VV
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0]

$ python3 perf_counter_across_processes.py 
Submitting worker 0 at time.perf_counter() == 2075.896
Submitting worker 1 at time.perf_counter() == 2076.900
Submitting worker 2 at time.perf_counter() == 2077.903
Worker 0 started at time.perf_counter() == 2075.900
Worker 1 started at time.perf_counter() == 2076.902
Worker 2 started at time.perf_counter() == 2077.905

$ python3.7 -VV
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55) 
[GCC 8.2.0]

$ python3.7 perf_counter_across_processes.py 
Submitting worker 0 at time.perf_counter() == 1692.514
Submitting worker 1 at time.perf_counter() == 1693.518
Submitting worker 2 at time.perf_counter() == 1694.520
Worker 0 started at time.perf_counter() == 1692.517
Worker 1 started at time.perf_counter() == 1693.519
Worker 2 started at time.perf_counter() == 1694.522
```

Comment: I've filed a bug report for this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue37205

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Windows, `time.perf_counter` is based on WINAPI `QueryPerformanceCounter`. This counter is system wide. For more information, see [acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps).

That said, `perf_counter` in Windows returns a value that's relative to the process startup value. Thus it is not a system-wide value. It does this in order to reduce precision loss when converting the integer value to a `float`, which has only 15 decimal digits of precision. Using a relative value is uncalled for in most cases, which only need microsecond precision. There should be an optional parameter to query the true QPC counter value, especially for `perf_counter_ns` in 3.7+.

Regarding the different initial values returned by `perf_counter` in 3.6 vs 3.7, the implementation has changed a bit over time. In 3.6.8, `perf_counter` is implemented in [Modules/timemodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.8/Modules/timemodule.c#L80), so the initial value is stored when the `time` module is first imported and initialized, which is why you see the first result as 0.000 seconds. In more recent releases it's implemented separately in Python's C API. For example, see ["Python/pytime.c"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0b1/Python/pytime.c#L937) in the latest 3.8 beta release. In this case, by the time Python code calls `time.perf_counter()`, the counter has incremented well past the startup value.

Here's an alternative implementation based on ctypes that uses the system-wide QPC value instead of a relative value.

```
import sys

if sys.platform != 'win32':
    from time import perf_counter
    try:
        from time import perf_counter_ns
    except ImportError:
        def perf_counter_ns():
            """perf_counter_ns() -> int

            Performance counter for benchmarking as nanoseconds.
            """
            return int(perf_counter() * 10**9)
else:
    import ctypes
    from ctypes import wintypes

    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

    kernel32.QueryPerformanceFrequency.argtypes = (
        wintypes.PLARGE_INTEGER,) # lpFrequency

    kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter.argtypes = (
        wintypes.PLARGE_INTEGER,) # lpPerformanceCount

    _qpc_frequency = wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER()
    if not kernel32.QueryPerformanceFrequency(ctypes.byref(_qpc_frequency)):
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    _qpc_frequency = _qpc_frequency.value

    def perf_counter_ns():
        """perf_counter_ns() -> int

        Performance counter for benchmarking as nanoseconds.
        """
        count = wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER()
        if not kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter(ctypes.byref(count)):
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
        return (count.value * 10**9) // _qpc_frequency

    def perf_counter():
        """perf_counter() -> float

        Performance counter for benchmarking.
        """
        count = wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER()
        if not kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter(ctypes.byref(count)):
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
        return count.value / _qpc_frequency
```

QPC typically has a resolution of 0.1 microseconds. A `float` in CPython has 15 decimal digits of precision. So this implementation of `perf_counter` is within the QPC resolution for an uptime of about 3 years.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer and workaround. I'm puzzled that there are no bug reports or code comments or Python mailing list discussions - that I've been able to find, at least - about this Windows-specific behavior that pretty clearly disagrees with the documentation. I guess I should submit a bug report!

Comment: Looking back through the commit history, it looks like the Windows implementation is [derived from](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ec89539ccccd6103665a7a5c7234cf09f27c1c72#diff-4a575e94d6ac98a0d82fd93509b6bfd3L91) that of `time.clock()`, where subtracting a process-specific offset was justified, since there was no guarantee of a system-wide value. In fact, `time.clock()` just [called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/timemodule.c#L162) `time.perf_counter()` until it was removed in 3.8.