# Python time.perf_counter zero-time synchrony between processes; OS-consistent?

Tags: python, time, operating-system, multiprocessing

I'm deploying across linux/macOS/Windows, and recently realized that `time.time()` on windows wasn't giving me sufficient precision, so I'm looking at switching to `time.perf_counter()`. I see that the [docs for perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) indicate that it doesn't have a defined zero-time, and should only be used for quantifying deltas. That's largely ok for my usage, except that my app spawns multiple processes through the multiprocessing module and I would like to be able to label events in separate processes and align them temporally later. Playing on linux there seems to be agreement on the zero time between Python sessions launched in different terminal windows, but am I safe to expect this agreement on macOS & Windows too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, found that someone already [asked something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502111/should-time-perf-counter-be-consistent-across-processes-in-python-on-windows), kicking off a bug report & fix that appears in 3.10.